# Code for creating a dialog for choosing a date

Tags: java, beginner, datetime, android, interface

I have code that creates an AlertDialog to select a date by a user. I ran into a problem that this code began to take up a lot of space. Could you offer ideas on how to shorten this code / put it into different methods. Thanks in advance

```
   public static AlertDialog getTextDialog(Context ctx, final OnSelectNewValueListener calendarListener) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.calendar_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setView(view);
    CalendarView calendar = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    TextView yearTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    TextView dateTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    Button cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    Button ok = view.findViewById(R.id.ok);

    AlertDialog calendarAlertDialog = builder.create();

    LocalDate currentDate = getLocalDateFromMilli(calendar.getDate());
    showCurrentDate(currentDate, yearTextView, dateTextView);

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener((view1, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
        LocalDate selectDate = LocalDate.of(year, Month.values()[month], dayOfMonth);
        showCurrentDate(selectDate, yearTextView, dateTextView);
        calendar.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(year,month,dayOfMonth).getTimeInMillis());
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        calendarAlertDialog.cancel();
    });

    ok.setOnClickListener(v->{
        calendarListener.onCalendarSelect(getLocalDateFromMilli(calendar.getDate()));
        calendarAlertDialog.cancel();
    });

    return calendarAlertDialog;
}

private static void showCurrentDate(LocalDate selectDate, TextView yearTextView, TextView dateTextView) {
    yearTextView.setText(String.valueOf(selectDate.getYear()));
    dateTextView.setText(selectDate.format(dateFormatMedium));
}

@Override
public void onCalendarSelect(LocalDate time) {
    date.setText(dateFormatShort.format(time));
}
```

OnSelectNewValueListener

```
interface OnSelectNewValueListener {
    void onCalendarSelect(LocalDate time);
}
```

Imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sgc.weightcontrol.R;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
```

Comment: Can you please include all imports used in this program?

Comment: Added, I really do not understand what it will give you

Comment: @Destroyer `import` statement will significantly affect the space consumed by your code, that's why Linny asked for it. You should remove any `import` statement that's not really needed to compile your code.#